# How do I redirect in a Flask application to the same page without the user being logged out?

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I'm new to programming - my first Flask and Python app, but I would really appreciate your help:

I have written a view that displays the users registered on a site (this is only accessible to the admin user). The admin can then use a switch on the same page to make each user a superuser. The switch is in a form, when the submit button is pressed, I want the new state of the user to be logged in the database (mongodb) and then redirect the admin user to the back same page.

The url on the user page before the redirect looks like this:
https://8080-abbyhumphreys-caravansy-jabahblvlqu.ws-eu96.gitpod.io/edit_users/**admin**
After submitting the form, the admin part is missing, like this:
https://8080-abbyhumphreys-caravansy-jabahblvlqu.ws-eu96.gitpod.io/edit_users/

So, it returns an 404 error:
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I understand that this is because my html template limits access of this page to the admin user only, but how do I keep admin logged in when it redirects?

Here is my route:

```
    @app.route("/edit_users/<user_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def edit_users(user_id):
        if request.method == "POST":
            is_superuser = "on" if request.form.get("is_superuser") else "off"
            apply = {
                "is_superuser": is_superuser
            }
            mongo.db.users.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(user_id)}, {"$set": apply})
            flash("User Update Applied")
            users = list(mongo.db.users.find())  # Fetch the updated user list
            return redirect(request.referrer)
        users = list(mongo.db.users.find())
        return render_template("edit_users.html", users=users)
```

Here is the html:

```
`    {% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h1 class="mb-5">Users List</h1>
                    <div class="card w-50 mx-auto border-0 rounded-0">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ">
                            {% for user in users %}
                                <li class="list-group-item d-inline-flex justify-content-between border-3 border-color-1 rounded-0 mb-1">
                                    <h4><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> {{ user.username|upper}}</h4>
                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit_users', user_id=users._id) }}">
                                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                            {% if user.is_superuser == "on" %}
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="is_superuser" name="is_superuser" checked>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="is_superuser" name="is_superuser">
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="is_superuser">Superuser</label>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    {% endblock %}`
```

Thank you!

I have tried:
`return redirect("edit_users", users=users)`
`return redirect(request.referrer)`
`return redirect(request.url)`